# HTML5 history storing only one state

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, html5-history

I am developing a Google Maps AJAX-application in JS/PHP and want to implement HTML5 History API.
I already implemented custom deeplinks so everything can be accessed with pretty URLs.

Now on AJAX get, I do the following to store history:

```
var stateObj = { id: obj.id };
history.pushState(stateObj, null, obj.deeplink);
```

and to retrieve it on browser back, I do:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
google.maps.event.trigger(markersArray[JSON.parse(event.state.id)], 'click');
};
```

However, only 1 step back is stored, so when I click back multiple times, it calls the same as when calling the first back.

What's wrong?

**More explanation**

Ok, it seems I have not provided enough code.
This is the general onpopstate-listener:

```
//get popstate event
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
   console.log('onpopstate: '+JSON.parse(event.state.id));
    google.maps.event.trigger(markersArray[JSON.parse(event.state.id)], 'click');
    };
```

On click on a map-marker, I do this:

```
//change URL, save state
history.pushState({ objId: obj.id }, obj.pagetitle, obj.deeplink);
```

But of course, the trigger of a marker-click onpopstate also leads to the history.pushState so I think it's overwriting the last value.

In the "history"-object, there's only one object, no matter how many markers where clicked.

Comment: I suspect that overwriting the stateObj-object is the problem, but I thought pushState would not replace but push the objects into storage...

Comment: great, a downvote without a comment. If you only could explain what's wrong about it?!

Comment: It's hard to tell with the code you provided. What is the output of `stateObj` in your different steps?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I've added additional info, hope that helps.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17804148/1238965) and eventually [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) that might help you to support the different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what happens is that when you click the element you do .pushState() but onpopstate() you just call onclick() function that pushes the same state information again, keeping you forever on that id.

As a solution you should only .pushState() if (history.state.id != this.id) or your current object id.

Comment: Exactly that was the problem. Thx