# HTML5 history API popstate event returns wrong data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-history, html5-history

HTML5 history API returns wrong history state data whenever **popstate** event occurs. Below are some **push** and **pop** event responses (I logged in console).

### JS

```
/*
 * JS USED TO PUSH HISTORY 
 */
var markers = [];
var markerIndexes = [];
// mapOverlays (array) is a global variable containing all marker and infowindow objects
var overlayIndex = mapOverlays.length; 
var historyData = {
    "historyDetails": {
        "append": true,
        "popState": false
    },
    "title": null,
    "url": ""
};
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    // this function creates a marker with infowindow and pushes marker & infowindow objects to mapOverlays array
    addActionMarkerToGMap(data[i].lat, data[i].lng, 'Demo info window', false);
}
for (var i = overlayIndex; i < mapOverlays.length; ++i) {
    markers.push(mapOverlays[i].marker);
    markerIndexes.push(i);
}
historyData.historyDetails.markerIndexes = markerIndexes;
window.history.pushState(historyData.historyDetails, historyData.title, historyData.url);


/*
 * POPSTATE EVENT HANDLER
 */
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
    if (event.state != null && event.state != "" && typeof event.state == "object") {
        var popstateData = {
            historyDetails: {
                append: event.state.append,
                popState: true, // hard coded because this is result of popstate event
                markerIndexes: event.state.markerIndexes
            }
        };
        console.log(popstateData);
    }
});
```

### Push state 1

JSON below is pushed when first AJAX request is complete.

```
    {  
   "historyDetails":{
      "append":false,
      "popState":false,
      "markerIndexes":[  
         0,
         1,
         2
      ]
   },
   "title":null,
   "url":""
}
```

### Push state 2

This JSON object is pushed to history when second AJAX request is complete.

```
{  
   "historyDetails":{  
      "append":true,
      "popState":false,
      "markerIndexes":[  
         3,
         4,
         5
      ]
   },
   "title":null,
   "url":""
}
```

### Pop state 1

And this is what I get when I hit **browser back** button. Pop state event returns **Push state 1** instead of **Push state 2**

```
{  
   "historyDetails":{  
      "append":false,
      "popState":true,
      "markerIndexes":[  
         0,
         1,
         2
      ]
   },
   "title":null,
   "url":""
}
```

As shown above, history API does not return most recent PUSH STATE data. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your actual history api code (where you push the state and where it is popped afterwards)?

Comment: @nils please check update. I've added **JS** to top.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior and is how the history api works.

See my answer that explains how push- and popstate works, in this thread: [Popstate - passing popped state to event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801614/popstate-passing-popped-state-to-event-handler)

Comment: But I want to get most recently pushed history state data. How do I do that?

Comment: Well seing as how the last pushstate is supposed to be your 'current state', you propably have your current state in a variable.

Comment: Your answer on that post (mentioned in answer above) is really very helpful but I expected ```popstate``` event to return most recently pushed history data. I think I should create my own **History Stack** with ```push and pop``` functions to manage history.

Comment: @webmasterjohn It's a common pitfall, and one I fell in my self.